# PLCrashReporter frameworks integration produce "Could not inspect the application package." error

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks, plcrashreporter

I am actually trying to integrate PLCrashReport using either a Framework (the one given on the official website) or Carthage.

Carthage won't compile the framework, and the manual drag & drop with the one downloaded from the website would produce the following error when installing the app on the device (Run build)

```
App installation failed
Could not inspect the application package.
```

I use a build target of iOS8, I linked the framework as an embedded binary to ship it with the app ; and this error is very annoying.

Xcode is in 7.3

Right now, I tried manual build for the framework, clean of the project. None would work.

By curiosity, I tried Cocoapod integration for this library, it worked, but Cocoapod is NOT an option on my project so I can't go with it.

Does anyone have had the same issue, any ideas for correcting it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a way to make it work :

PLCrashReporter should NOT be in `embedded frameworks`, just in `linked frameworks`. Works like a charm now, debug and release builds !